# ggplot for multiple values in the same row

Tags: r

I have a data frame with multiple values in the same row

```
index price

1   1000,2000,3000

2   2000,500
```

The data frame has 12 rows and not all `price` rows have equal length. I want to plot `index` vs `price` with `index` along x-axis and `price` along y-axis. I have the following code-

```
ggplot(data_m,
   aes(x = 1:12,
       y = data_m$price))
```

I get the error- `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): y`

How do I plot every value in the price column?

Comment: Hi @Misha, you'll want to get your data in a `tidy` format. See here: https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf where each column contains only 1 value per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this. You have to reshape data and then look for the strategy to plot as mentioned by **@TheSciGuy**. Here a `tidyverse` approach using `separate_rows()` to split values in your rows and then a `full_join()` to compact with the index you wish. Next the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data and plot
df %>% separate_rows(price,sep=',') %>%
  mutate(price=as.numeric(price)) %>%
  full_join(data.frame(index=1:12)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(index),y=price))+
  geom_point()+
  xlab('index')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(index = 1:2, price = c("1000,2000,3000", "2000,500"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

And if you want some color per index:

```
#Data and plot 2
df %>% separate_rows(price,sep=',') %>%
  mutate(price=as.numeric(price)) %>%
  full_join(data.frame(index=1:12)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(index),y=price,color=factor(index)))+
  geom_point()+
  xlab('index')+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]